# How to set vue data to the value of a form?

Tags: flask, vue.js

I have a flask page that is for editing blog posts. It has the following vue:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('edit',itemid=item.id) }}" id="text-input">
            {{ form.csrf_token }}
            <div style="margin-left:30px;margin-top:20px;">
                Title: {{ form.title }}
            </div>
            <br/>

            <div id="editor">
            Content: {{ form.content( **{':value':'input','@input': 'update'}) }}
                <div v-html="compiledMarkdown"></div>
            </div>
            <br/>
            Category: {{ form.category|safe }}
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Save">
        </form>
<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#editor',
  data: {
    input: "starting data"
  },
  computed: {
    compiledMarkdown: function () {
      return marked(this.input, { sanitize: true })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    update: _.debounce(function (e) {
      this.input = e.target.value
    }, 300)
  }
});
</script>
```

What I would like to do is have a starting value for input based on something sent in by flask. Basically I would change input: "starting data" to input: {{ form.content.data }}. However, when I do this, it stops updating the input when I change the text in the box. I think I am kind of hardcoding the data to be whatever what in form.content.data as opposed to a string.

How can I pass this in so that it starts with the form.content.data value yet is still changeable?

Comment: Does you `form.content` show "starting data" when it's rendered?

Comment: yep. form.content.data does. But I just realized the problem is I needed quotes around the template tag, like  '{{ form.content.data }}' . Before it was trying to define the variable as that text instead of the string and couldn't do it. Now everything works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it didn't work was because `{{ form.content.data }}` appears in the template as raw text.

Thus it was trying to use something like: the brown fox jumped over the lazy dog

and this doesn't compile to a javascript object. Adding quotes around the `{{ form.content.data }}` like `'{{ form.content.data }}'` fixed it.